# How to scan the unmanaged package in salesforce using OWASP ZAP Tool?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, unmanaged-package

How to scan the unmanaged package in salesforce using OWASP ZAP Tool. I am new to use Zap tool. I created a unmanaged package with Lightning web components and i am having installed package url. I need to scan the package LWC components using Zap tool. can anyboby help me on this.

Comment: OWASP Zap tool is a tool for scanning HTTP services, not Salesforce packages. For Salesforce packages you HAVE to use Checkmarx, there are some free scans available at https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner#

Comment: @zaitsman Thanks for your update. I have LWC Component bundle, can i scan the lightning component using OWASP Zap Tool.

Comment: simple answer is no, not as far as I am aware